# Plot 3D Grid Data as Heat Map using matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

I tried to visualize data as a cube but want to plot each cell inside the cube.

This is a [cube not divided by cell](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6hF61.png) but I want this [3D heatmap](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zBnLl.png)

I need to visualize the predicted result in a 3D cube with a heatmap

Here is the code:

```
%matplotlib notebook
%matplotlib inline
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
matplotlib.rcParams['backend'] = "Qt4Agg"
import numpy as np

#each sell has its value

y_pred = ([-3.4942558e+01, -1.0922590e+01, -9.4551229e+00, -2.6156654e+01,
        1.1722648e+01,  6.4425749e-01, -1.1141028e+01,  5.9728470e+01,
       -4.5249408e-01, -8.7741699e+00,  9.9452820e+00, -2.8595707e+00,
        2.6979692e+00,  7.9802217e+00, -1.1204488e+00, -4.5213123e+01,
       -7.1909481e-01, -8.4901733e+00, -9.2283611e+00,  5.0730385e+01,
       -7.9520082e-01,  1.4589276e+02,  8.4267479e+01, -6.7399621e+00,
        2.1536992e+02,  5.0958019e+01, -7.7071385e+00,  8.4650040e+01,
        2.5421507e+01, -4.1403370e+00, -8.5559702e+00,  5.5478176e+01,
       -1.0955868e+01,  3.1425345e+02,  1.9285686e+02,  4.6105843e+00,
        6.6680554e+02,  2.7745572e+02,  1.2241451e+01,  5.1578967e+02,
        1.8129390e+02,  7.3322144e+00,  1.2733205e+02,  4.4435711e+01,
       -2.0441423e-01,  8.3673248e+01,  1.7386259e+02, -1.6146477e-01,
        5.9598431e+02,  5.7501422e+02,  4.7413929e+01,  7.6495886e+02,
        6.5124884e+02,  7.9399048e+01,  4.0769174e+02,  3.2358469e+02,
        3.6726327e+00,  7.5896362e+01,  9.8999245e+01, -1.7699455e+00,
        1.0632815e+02,  2.3123619e+02,  4.5826878e+01,  3.6063211e+02,
        5.6004309e+02,  1.3757048e+02,  3.7029037e+02,  5.5426331e+02,
        1.0625824e+02,  1.7360068e+02,  2.6583237e+02,  2.0798336e+01,
        4.7036118e+01,  7.3350151e+01,  9.1420832e+00])

ex1 = np.trunc(y_pred).reshape(5,5,3)

max_value = np.amax(ex1)
min_value = np.amin(ex1)
average = 1/2*(min_value + max_value)
mean_value = np.mean(ex1)
print(f"max: {max_value}\nmin: {min_value}\naverage: {average}\nmean: {mean_value}")

x = 5
y = 5
z = 3

axes = [5, 5, 3]
data = np.ones(axes, dtype=bool)

alpha = 0.5

colors = np.empty(axes + [4])

for x1 in range(x):
    for y1 in range(y):
        for z1 in range(z):
            if ex1[x1][y1][z1] >= average: 
                colors[x1][y1][z1] = [1, 0, 0, alpha] 
                
            elif ex1[x1][y1][z1] > mean_value:
                colors[x1][y1][z1] = [1, 1, 0, alpha] 
            
            elif ex1[x1][y1][z1] <= mean_value:
                colors[x1][y1][z1] = [0, 0, 1, alpha]        
    
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')
ax.voxels(data, facecolors=colors, edgecolors='grey')
ax.axis('on')
ax.set_aspect('auto')

plt.show()
```

I would really appreciate it if you help me with this

Comment: What is the problem? Why the output of this program you posted is not satisfying?

Comment: I can't turn my code into what I want to create. If you run this code, you get the cube not divided by cell. But I want this cube to be divided into cells and get colored similarly to a heatmap. (Please see 3D heatmap picture)